# Make All select dropdowns have first option selected after current select

Tags: jquery

Suppose, I have following select dropdowns:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="lForm">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="Click1" id="Click1">
                <option value="1">op 1</option>
                <option value="2">op 2</option>
                <option value="3">op 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="Click2" id="Click2">
                <option value="1">op 1</option>
                <option value="2">op 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="Click3" id="Click3">
                <option value="1">op 1</option>
                <option value="2">op 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="Click4" id="Click4">
                <option value="1">op 1</option>
                <option value="2">op 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Now, my question is:

- Click1 is selected, then Click2 Click3 Click4 should be reset to first option selected.
- Click2 is selected, then Click3 Click4 should be reset to first option selected.
- Click3 is selected, then Click4 should be reset to first option selected.

I know, if I want to make all select dropdowns to have first option selected, then following works:

```
$("#1Form select:not(:eq(0)) option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$("#1Form select:not(:eq(0)) option:first").prop('selected','selected');
```

But it works when we need to make all select to have first option selected. 
Can anyone give me direction how to make next other dropdowns to have first option selected after current select is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `change` event and [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

`prop('selectedIndex', 0)` - sets first option as selected

```js
$('#lForm select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parent('td').nextAll().find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="lForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Click1" id="Click1">
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
          <option value="3">op 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Click2" id="Click2">
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Click3" id="Click3">
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Click4" id="Click4">
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can get the `index()` of the `select` which was changed, then use `:gt()` to reset the values of all `select` with a higher index. Try this:

```js
var $select = $('select').on('change', function() {
  var index = $(this).index('select');
  $select.filter(':gt(' + index + ')').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="lForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Click1" id="Click1">
          <option value="">Select 1</option>
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
          <option value="3">op 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Click2" id="Click2">
          <option value="">Select 2</option>
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Click3" id="Click3">
          <option value="">Select 3</option>
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Click4" id="Click4">
          <option value="">Select 4</option>
          <option value="1">op 1</option>
          <option value="2">op 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```